# How to use built-in Map in custom Map in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a class named `Map`， and I want to define a member variables as built-in `Map`.
Here is my code.

`class Map {`

`constructor() {`

`this.myMap = new Map();`

`}`

`}`

It seems like system will recognize it as a recursive call.

I can use object instead of built-in `Map`, but I want to use float number as the key.

Comment: You should just not name your class `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to `window.Map` to get the global Map instead of this particular class.

```js
class Map {
    constructor() {
        this.myMap = new window.Map();
    }
}
const m = new Map();
m.myMap.set('foo', 'bar');
console.log('done');
```